# xml onreadystatechange javascript not formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xmlhttprequest, horizontal-scrolling

I have a Database of images, and my website is using a small ajax function to poke the server, retrieve the list of images and format accordingly.

You can view the live version here: http://tbremer.com (live links are Architecture and Concerts).

My two issues are as follows:

1. The data (images) are not being formatted how I would like them to (horizontal display)
2. the body isn't scrolling when images do display properly.

Now for the weirdness.
On first click the images always display vertically, but if you click the same link again the images format correctly, horizontally and all DIVs are sized appropriately.

I'll post the code below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="imageViewer"></div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
//___ Ajax call for images
function loadXMLDoc() {
    //___ Variables
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("imageViewer").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

            var div = document.getElementById("imageViewer");
            var newDivWidth = 0;
            var imageViewerDivWidth = 290;

            for (i=0;i<div.children.length;i++) {
                //console.log(div.children[i]);

                var imageWidth = $("#portImage"+i).width();
                newDivWidth = imageWidth + newDivWidth + 4;
                console.log(imageWidth+" px.");
                console.log(newDivWidth);
            }

            imageViewerDivWidth = imageViewerDivWidth + newDivWidth;
            $("#contentWrapper").width(imageViewerDivWidth);
            $("#imageViewer").css("width", imageViewerDivWidth);
            console.log("");
        }

    }
    console.log(portLink); //Display link clicked
    xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/displayimagesLive.php?portname="+portLink,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
require("connect.php");

#___ Get variables from navigation
$portname = $_GET['portname'];
$queryMain = "SELECT id, portfolioName, filename FROM portfolio WHERE portfolioName='".$portname."' AND filename IS NOT NULL";
$getPortSQL = mysql_query($queryMain);

#___ Display!
$i = 0;
while ($nt = mysql_fetch_array($getPortSQL)) {
        echo "<div id='portImage".$i."' class='portImage'>";
            echo "<img src='images/portfolio/$nt[portfolioName]/$nt[filename]' height='500px'>";
        echo "</div>";
    $i++;
}
unset($i);
?>
```

**RELATIVE CSS**

```
/* Content Wrapper */
#contentWrapper {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;

    z-index: 0;

    border: 0px solid #600;
}

/* Image Viewer */

#imageViewer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;

    padding: 0px;
    padding-left: 350px;
    margin: 0px;

    border: 0px solid #F0F;
}

.portImage {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 4px;

    border: 1px solid #000;

    float: left;
}
```

Comment: If images act incorrectly the first time, but properly the second time, the most likely cause is the images not being loaded prior to trying to access their width and height. The solution would be to preload the images prior to getting their width and height.

Comment: @KevinB Good thought, am I wrong to assume though that the xmlhttp.readyState & xmlhttp.status should at least do some loading?

Or perhaps it's better to do loading in my PHP work? Since images are pulled dynamically, I don't know how to load the images before they are called for.

Comment: the xmlhttp.readyState checks the readystate of the XML, not the images in the xml. Here's another question that I answered with a simple image preload script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503143/fadein-and-fadeout-cross-browser/9503511#9503511

Comment: @KevinB The preloader helped, and some CSS changes also helped, however I am still having some issues with the horizontal format.